# Cant use --pipe for redis bulk insert

Tags: nosql, redis, bulkinsert

I am using Redis for storing large sets of data.   I am trying to use the bulk insert as described in the official documentation.  However, when I run the command,

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

Redis tells me that command --pipe has not been found.   I am using version 2.4.13.
Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe mode has been introduced with redis 2.4.14.
Try to upgrade your version of Redis.

Changelog for Redis 2.4:
https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.4/00-RELEASENOTES

Changelog for Redis 2.6:
https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.6/00-RELEASENOTES

Be sure to read http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert before using this feature.

Comment: ah that will do it.   Thanks. Ill get it upgraded tonight.